# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tableDnD is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Actually I'm trying to develope a drag and drop gridview with c#, I have look for some jquery library like tableDnD and following some examples I see a piece of code. I'm trying to reply it with my code but I have a

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tableDnD is not a function.
```

My code it's simple and I want to explain it:

Firstly this is a Master Page with this code:

```
<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Coaching.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2848/js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="js/javascript">
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var strorder;
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#grdResultados').tableDnD(
       {
           onDrop: function (table, row) {
               reorder();
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "diagnostico-plantilla.aspx/GridViewReorders",
                   data: '{"Reorder":"' + strorder + '"}',
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: true,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function (msg) {
                       alert("Successfully Save ReOrder");
                   }

               })
           }
       }
       );
   });
   function reorder() {
       strorder = "";
       var totalid = $('#grdResultados tr td input').length;
       for (var i = 0; i < totalid; i++) {
           strorder = strorder + $('#grdResultados tr td input')[i].getAttribute("value") + "|";
       }
   }
</script>
```

As you can see it's a simple Master Page, then the aspx has this line where I write the gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdResultados" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" AllowPaging="True" 
                            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="odsResultados" OnRowDataBound="grdResultados_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanged="grdResultados_PageIndexChanged" OnSorting="grdResultados_Sorting" OnRowCommand="grdResultados_RowCommand">
```

So, why I have this mistake, because when I try to do the drag and drop, it doesn't work and I have used the Chrome inspector and I had this.

Thanks so much

Comment: The error implies that the script for that plugin was not loaded. Are you sure the absolute path you have to it on `localhost:2848` is correct?

Comment: If I don't write the absolute path which is what I have written I have another mistake which is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and it shows this url http://localhost:2848/gestionplantillas/js/jquery.tablednd.js when the true url is http://localhost:2848/js/jquery.tablednd.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
<script src="http://localhost:2848/js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="js/javascript">
```

With this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/jquery.tablednd.js"></script>
```

If that fixes the problem you know that you were not referencing the `tablednd.js` file correctly.The easiest way to add a reference to a local .js file is to drag if from Visual Studio - Solution Explorer to the page.

Comment: What do you mean with  the problem you know that you were not referencing the tablednd.js file correctly.The easiest way to add a reference to a local .js file is to drag if from Visual Studio - Solution Explorer to the page.  I don't under stand. Thanks